# Linking libraries opencv cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to link my library and opencv library. Cmake is working properly, solution is build but linker error occurs. It seems as cmake couldnt link opencv lib with my library.

[This is an error which visual studio has.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAulM.jpg)

[CMakeLists configuration for opencv lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyqj4.jpg)

This is piece of CMakeLists conf responsible for linking libs.

```
# link libs
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I would be very grateful for you help.

Answer (score 0):

CMakeLists.txt I use for OpenCV apps configuring.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set (PROJ_NAME YourAppName)
project(${PROJ_NAME})
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV)

set(folder_source   main.cpp
                    )

set(folder_header   main.h
                    )

SOURCE_GROUP("Source Files" FILES ${folder_source})
SOURCE_GROUP("Header Files" FILES ${folder_header})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJ_NAME} ${folder_source} ${folder_header})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJ_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

it works fine, but check your opencv path does not contain spaces

(it does not like paths like "C:/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/opencv_build").